# Function similar to MD5() for random string generation (preferably crypto-secure)

Tags: php, random, md5

Currently working on a PHP project where I need to create a 9 character key, and recently came upon the MD5() function which I know is capable of creating a 32 character randomization, but is there anyway to shorten it down?

Is there another function that could possibly do a random number and letter combination of shorter length? I wrote a little algorithm for concatenating something similar a while back but having trouble injecting it into my code. The ID should be somewhat secure, and the DB will be checked for dups.

Comment: "secure" is irrelevant when you're talking about creating a random string..

Comment: md5 only returns hexadecimal characters; b64 encoding on the other hand has a 250k times bigger output space.

Answer (score 3):

Why not `substr` ? For example :

```
$code = substr(md5(time()), 0, 9);
```

Comment: I was considering this method. I'm just a little confused on the parameters it takes. You pass time into md5 which gives you the random number and then the substr takes the characters from 0 to 9? Am I reading that correctly?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It won't be crypto-secure, because no hash method will be, but it could be sufficient for generating id.
You could add a salt to your hash, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at uniqid()

https://www.php.net/uniqid

Comment: Another great idea. I was a little confused on the prefix and parameters the function took, but I will take it into consideration. The PHP manual threw up a big red flag about how it isn't crypto-secure but I've come to understand that random gen in PHP is pretty secure for everyday application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the system's pseudo random source, either directly or using a hash function:

```php
// direct
echo substr(base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(7)), 0, 9);

// via hash function
echo substr(base64_encode(sha1(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(7), true)), 0, 9);
```

Using Base-64 encoding generates an output space of `64 ^ 9` whereas the output of `md5()` has a mere `16 ^ 9` (250k times smaller). The range of this encoding is `[A-Za-z0-9+/]`; you can choose to substitute `+` and `/` by `-` and `_` respectively.

See also: [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`](http://php.net/openssl_random_pseudo_bytes)

**Update**

You can remove the `+` and `/` from Base-64 by a simple transformation:

```
strtr($output, '/+', 'Zz');
```

It duplicates two letters, but in the grand scheme of things it will have little impact on its uniqueness.

Comment: Jack, thank you for your feedback. I am now considering using this method. one question however. Is there any parameter that can filter the result to be alpha numeric? EDIT: I found the convert_uuencode method in the PHP manual. Would this work?

Comment: @AndrewL You mean only letters and numbers?

Comment: Thanks for the update! :) I assume we set the substr to a variable and pass the variable through the strtr method and make it a two step process? Also, I take it since we are swapping / and + there will be no truncation and the string will still be nine characters in length?

Comment: @AndrewL Right, you can apply `strtr()` at any point after `base64_encode()` .. doesn't matter.